# Cropping live video input from a webcam for facial identification

Tags: python, opencv, facial-identification

I am working with OpenCV in Python for facial identification and I want to crop the live video from my webcam to just output the face it recognizes.

I have tried using ROI but I do not know how to correctly implement it.

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
# Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        roi = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cropped = frame[roi]


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Face', cropped)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ben/Desktop/facerecog/facerecog2.py", line 31, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('Face', cropped)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2492: error: (-206:Bad flag (parameter or structure field)) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function 'cvGetMat'
```

Comment: as for me `roi` is already cropped image and you shoud display `roi` instead of `cropped`

Comment: `x1,y1` top-left coordinates and `x2,y2` bottom-right coordinates. To crop ROI from an image `cropped_img = image[y1:y2,x1:x2]`

Answer (score 0):

You get cropped image with

```
cropped = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

and then you can display it.

---

But sometimes there is no face on frame and it will not create `cropped` and you can get error. Better create this variabel before `for` and check it after `for`

```
cropped = None

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cropped = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

if cropped is not None:
    cv2.imshow('Face', cropped)
#else:
#    cv2.imshow('Face', frame)
```

or

```
if faces:
    (x, y, w, h) = faces[0]
    cropped = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('Face', cropped)
```

---

I don't know what you want to do if there will be many faces on frame.